# How to block urls with .jpg using FF extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm creating a FF addon. I want to block all the URLs with .jpg *(or any other user defined extension)* in a page.

How to do it??

Comment: it's been 7 minutes since you asked your question. Stack Overflow is a not an instant answer service. I recommend you a) Calm down (i.e, chop of the trailing question marks, it gives the appearance of a hysteric) b) provide some more specifics to your problem - show what you have tried, what you're stuck on, etc.  Thanks and Good Luck!

Comment: @Thomas, thanks for the reply :) Ya, I'm impatient :( i've been stuck in the above said problem for days. The below below is exactly what i want. But i cant understand his explanations :( http://blog.webmynd.com/2011/04/04/equivalent-to-beforeload-event-for-firefox-extensions/

Comment: I just would like to point out the question is no a problem asking for help but more of a feature request.  It is no better than "I want to make an app like ms word how do I do that" SO is not for this please provide your attempts short coming and successes.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming by URLs, you mean `<a>` elements, then the following code would remove all jpg/gif/png links which end with those extensions. If you wish to change it to images, you can change the elements that are searched from `a` to `img`, and change the search test from `href` to `src`.

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/n3KJm/).

```
var m = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    var patt = new RegExp("^https?://(?:[a-z\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:/[^/#?]+)+\.(?:jpg|gif|png)$","i");
    var removed = 0;
    for (i=0; i<m.length;){
        if (patt.test(m[i].href)){
            // it got matched, remove it
            m[i].parentNode.removeChild(m[i]);
            removed++;
        }else{
            i++;
        }

    }
    alert(removed+" image url's removed");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your code helped me a lot. This code will code before the pictures begin to download ?

Comment: If you run it on document load, the images will have started loading, but will be removed faster than a user would notice. However, the http request may be sent before it removes the links from the DOM.

Comment: I'm afraid, i'm asking you too much. How to prevent http request being sent? Seems like this link will help but i cant understand how to use it https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads